# C++ look-up USB devices mount point

Tags: c++, linux, usb, libusb

I need to look-up the USB devices connected to the computer board running Linux.
To do so I have used 'libusb' library, which works great and I can retrieve the manufacturer, serial nnumber, product id, etc...

The problem is that I need to know the mount point in the file system so I can pass this information to another function.

Any idea?

thanks in advance.

Carles.

Comment: http://www.known-issues.net/cpp/how-to-detect-if-dev-is-a-usb-device.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question -
https://superuser.com/questions/361885/how-do-i-figure-out-which-dev-is-a-usb-flash-drive
goes over a lot about disks and information concerning them.

However I want to point you to the answer further down the page: https://superuser.com/a/361893 as it explains how to find where the disks are located.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not only hardd rives but any kind of USB device that I need to know the mount point, for instance /dev/ttyUSB0 ...

Comment: @user2282474 The file `/dev/tty/USB0` is not a "mount point", it's the device node for that particular device. A "mount point" can only be used for devices hosting actual file systems, and would be something like `/media/user2282474/MYFLASHDRIVE` on Ubuntu.